Azure Function apps and event grid hooks setup question
I am in the process of finalizing my EventHandlers using Azure Event Grid, and I have thought of a problem I might have in managing them.
I am programming in C# so my event handlers are be Azure Function Apps and have to be subscribed as Web Hooks.
Now my question is if I have says 10 different Azure Function App Event Handlers is it better to put them in a single Function app with different endpoints or is it much better to put them into different app Functions.
I mean there is clearly a bigger management burden if I have them all in different app functions, but let's say I have to update one Event Handler, if they are all in the same Function App, will that cause outages on all the other event handlers in that Function App, and will I need to resubscribe them after every update?
So is better to put all the Event Handlers in their own Function Apps?

Use a single Function App if handlers have similar workloads, shared configurations, and low update frequency or opt for separate Function Apps if uptime and independent scaling are critical or if handlers differ significantly in performance needs.

The decision depends on your priorities for isolation, scalability, and management.
In case of single function app (with multiple endpoints)
Pros: Easier management and deployment, shared resources.
Cons: Redeploying the app for one handler can briefly affect all handlers. However, you typically do not need to resubscribe after updates unless the app URL changes.
In case of multiple function apps (one handler per app):
Pros: Isolation ensures updates to one handler do not affect others. Each app scales independently, making it better for handlers with varying workloads or configurations.
Cons: Higher management overhead.
As mentioned earlier, use a single function app if handlers have similar workloads, shared configurations, and low update frequency. Go for separate function apps if uptime and independent scaling are critical or if handlers differ significantly in performance needs.
Checkout below docs from MS for further clarity-

Improve the performance and reliability of Azure Functions
Use a function as an event handler for Event Grid events
Event-driven scaling in Azure Functions

